# sftp packet length error with loaded .bashrc

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp, bashrc

I regularly use WinSCP to tranfer a few files to my personal server. However I recently experienced the infamous "bad packet length" error due to one of my echo statements residing inside the .bashrc file. 
Therefore with respect to this: [sftp corruption error](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/sftp-corruption.auto.html) I would like to ask the following:

Why did the system complained for an echo statement (or whatever is causing the error) residing within my .bashrc file and not my .bash_profile instead?

..if the sftp is some sort of subprocess spawned by the ssh server as the above link suggests, shouldn't it first parse the .bash_profile file and complain about its own echo statements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following line (two with comment) at the top of my *.bashrc*, it simply aborts if it isn't an interactive shell:

```
# if we're not an interactive shell, do nothing
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

I suppose if you want the long form:

```
# if we're not an interactive shell, do nothing
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
    return
fi
```

This mitigates the need for a *.bashrc_profile* file, since the *.bashrc* changes how it responds based on how it was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` executes for login shells.  `.bashrc` executes for interactive shells.  Apparently, WinSCP must be creating a non-login interactive shell on the remote machine.  Details can be found in the `INVOCATION` section of the Bash man page.

Comment: Shouldn't WinSCP create a non-login non-interactive shell instead? I can't see how a session is considered interactive without a shell...

Comment: One could argue that, but it all depends on how WinSCP uses the SSH protocol.